# Issue in password field validation asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, validation

I have to make validation for password. It works fine but if i add runat=server my password validation does not work.And when i remove runat server it works fine.

my code is as:

```
<input value=""  runat="server" class="validate[required] text-input" type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" name="password" id="password" />


    <input value="" runat="server"  class="validate[required,equals[password]] text-input" type="password" name="password2" id="password2" />
```

Any help on this topic will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have taken normal HTML tag telling to act as server side control i,e runat="Server".Normal html control will not work as server side control,So please take asp.net controls and write required code.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"/>
```

Comment: @Imad,Need to write something like this <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtpsw" TextMode="Password" class="validate[required] text-input" /> and required pattern should be added in codebehind.

Comment: 1 point for simple and rapid answer. I want to answer after one of my other works and back in 10 minutes and saw you answered. :) Thanks.

Comment: @Shankar we don't really need it. difference between

<input type = "text"> and <asp:TextBox> is just stateful nature box <asp:TextBox> and some other otherwise both are accessible from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

when you put space in control properties `asp` create  diffrent properties for element 
in your textbox control you are creating properties like 
`required pattern`
So, `ASP`  Create your text box html like this

```
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" required="" pattern="asdsa" class="validate[required] text-input" />
```

**Answer**

So you need to create properties using code behind

you can Add control attribute at code behind if you having problem in `ASP` page

```
<input value=""  runat="server" class="validate[required] text-input" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
```

at code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    password.Attributes.Add("required pattern","(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}");

}
```

Comment: Dear you have not understood my issue. Actually the problem is, it shows me, password do not match even if both the passwords i give are same.